# Web browser can't detect correctly installed webcam on Linux

Tags: linux, webcam

Any web browser can't access to my webcam. I figured out that the camera is correctly installed using Cheese. The web cam is a Logitech QuickCam V-UAP14. I've tested the camera in my PC with OpenSuse 13.2 and another PC with CentOS 7, the same issue in both.

What can I do to use my webcam through any browser?

Comment: What context were you thinking of ... maybe a Flash application? In this case Flash might be the culprit.

Comment: HTML5 and Flash applications doesn't work.